# Show local notifications without limit

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uilocalnotification

I have a swift 2 app in which you can create entries in Core Data.
Each entry will register a local notification.

The problem is the limit of 64 local notifications.
Is there an way to solve this "problem" with the limitation?

Comment: See e.g. [this obj-c repo](https://github.com/vangelov/VLDLocalNotificationsScheduler) circumventing the 64 notification limit by using queuing. Possibly you can make use of similar techniques in your Swift project.

Answer (score 2):

Kind of (thanks @dfri). However, repeated notifications only count as one notification, but it appears that you have 64 completely independent notifications.

From the [Local and Remote Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH102-SW1):

> Each app on a device is limited to 64 scheduled local notifications. The system discards scheduled notifications in excess of this limit, keeping only the 64 notifications that will fire the soonest. Recurring notifications are treated as a single notification.

The only semi-viable alternative is (see [this repo](https://github.com/vangelov/VLDLocalNotificationsScheduler)):

1. Hope that your users open your app within 64 notifications.
2. Schedule remaining notifications.

Comment: I'd say point `2` above is viable enough to _"solve this "problem" with the notification"_, so a set-in-stone _"Nope"_ is not really the case here. See e.g. [this obj-c repo](https://github.com/vangelov/VLDLocalNotificationsScheduler) circumventing the 64 notification limit by using queuing (which I believe, is a fully viable solution).

Comment: or is there any way to register the next notification after the first one was showing ?

Comment: @dfri Nice, I'll change it to "kind of" :)

Comment: @GhostStack The notifications are copied to the system so there is no way to simply run some code once a notification fires.

Comment: is there an swift solution by using queuing ?

Comment: @GhostStack You can call objective-c code from swift.

Comment: but i need a swift solution :/

Comment: @GhostStack If you want a swift solution, then you'll have to build a custom one yourself.

Comment: sry i dont understand this with the queue. how can i put my notifications into a queue, and how will it works that the notifications will be shown step by step?

Comment: @GhostStack Ask a separate question.

Comment: Apple link broken. Here's [the link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH3-SW1) but I'm not seeing the source of the quotation. [UILocalNotification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilocalnotification) mentions it but that is deprecated now.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43424044/limit-for-local-notifications-unnotificationrequest-in-ios-10)

Comment: @shim One of the Apple developers at the notifications lab at WWDC did say the limit is still in place. You could also try making a demo app to confirm that's still the case.

Comment: Mostly concerned about the lack of documentation. Was this a recorded WWDC talk?

Comment: @shim No it was at one of the labs.