# Limit for Local Notifications (UNNotificationRequest) in iOS 10

Tags: ios, unnotificationrequest

I know that the limit of local notifications is 64 for **UILocalNotification**. It's written in [Apple Dev Docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uilocalnotification#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UILocalNotification). But UILocalNotification is deprecated in iOS 10. Instead this one, Apple proposes to use **UNNotificationRequest**. But [Apple Dev Docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unnotificationrequest) doesn't say anything about limiting the count of notifications.
I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40685128/is-there-still-a-64-local-notification-limit-for-the-new-usernotifications-in-i), but it doesn't have links to Apple Dev Docs or something like that (it's just an opinion).
Does anyone know for sure about restrictions of local notifications?
Maybe someone know the link to Dev Docs or is there an official response from Apple about this?

Answer (score 12):

Although it's not officially documented, [testing shows](http://ileyf.cn.openradar.appspot.com/38065340) that `UNNotificationRequest` retains the 64 notification limit.

However, importantly, the way that they deal with the notification queue has changed. If there are more than 64 notifications:

- `UILocalNotification` would keep the 64 **soonest** notifications
- `UNNotificationRequest` keeps the 64 **last set** notifications

This may be a bug, and is documented in this [radar](http://ileyf.cn.openradar.appspot.com/38065340).

Comment: Thanks for finding this out!!

Answer (score 4):

The IOS 12 version of `UNNotificationCenter.h` has in comments of `(void)addNotificationRequest:(UNNotificationRequest *)request withCompletionHandler:(nullable void(^)(NSError *__nullable error))completionHandler;` this:

> Notification requests can be scheduled to notify the user via time and location. See UNNotificationTrigger for more information. Calling -addNotificationRequest: will replace an existing notification request with the same identifier. A notification request with the identifier as an existing delivered notifications will alert for the new notification request and replace the existing delivered notification when it is triggered. **The number of pending notification requests that may be scheduled by an application at any one time is limited by the system**.

Answer (score 1):

Yes indeed, I just checked for iOS 10.2 and the limit for the total number of UNNotificationRequest you can add is still 64.

Comment: [Documentation for UNNotificationRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationrequest) doesn't mention it. Nor is it in the [notification guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH3-SW1). Do you have an official source that mentions it? I don't doubt the limit exists, but would like to see if it is documented.

Comment: "An app can have only a limited number of scheduled notifications; the system keeps the soonest-firing 64 notifications (with automatically rescheduled notifications counting as a single notification) and discards the rest." (Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilocalnotification#overview)

Comment: @LukasSchulze `UILocalNotification` is deprecated since iOS 10. New class `UNNotificationRequest` mentions no limit to schedule amount.