# Local notifications not working in iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I am using local notifications in my app.

Now that iOS 11 is out there they are not working anymore. I haven't seen anything that could cause this in the release docs, does anyone know what could be causing this?

I know it's deprecated but i see no reason why it shouldn't just work anyway.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you have to use UNUserNotificationCenter, it is available from iOS 10

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems there is a bug in iOS11. I can see if I schedule more than the 64 allowed notifications it ignores all the notifications I schedule.

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilocalnotification) state the system keeps the soonest firing 64 notifications and discards the rest. On iOS11 it just discards them all...

So the fix in my case was to make dead-sure not to schedule more than 64 notifications.

Comment: With the new UNNotification it's still 64 although not mentioned in docs, and on iOS 11 it's keeping the last set 64 according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/52614542/1032900